# Is there a click() function for images?

Tags: javascript

Is there a `click()` function for images? Not an `onClick` function, but an actual `click()` function like buttons have

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by the second part? What `click()` function?

Comment: there is a click function for buttons, for instance:
document.getElementById("niceButton").click();

Answer (score 2):

No, images don't have a `click` function.

Compare the IDL for [HTMLImageElement](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-17701901) (no `click` listed) with the IDL for [HTMLInputElement](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-6043025) (`click` listed).

(Interestingly, though, the HTML5 spec — which is more recent — no longer shows a `click` function on `HTMLInputElement`s. Links: [HTML5 `HTMLImageElement`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-img-element.html#the-img-element) - [HTML5 `HTMLInputElement`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-input-element.html#the-input-element).)

Comment: Im a beginner, how do i do that?

Comment: @user1789462: Follow the links and look at the functions each element type is meant to have. IDL just stands for "Interface Definition Language", think of it as an API doc.

Comment: @pst I had the same confusion.

Comment: @JimSchubert: It was a typo. :-O *Images* never had it, *Inputs* did in the DOM2 HTML spec but don't in the HTML5 spec.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

you can also try this jQuery solution

```
<img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" />
```

bind event like this:

```
$(function () {
  $("img").click(function() {
    alert('Hello World!');  
  });
});
```

---

**javascript and html solution**

I think that is not but you can do work around like this

```
<a href="#" onClick="alert('Hello World!')"><img title="The Link" /></a>
```

this makes your image clickable

Comment: the image is already clickable, but i just cant find a way to click it through javascript

Answer (score 0):

Put the image in a button.

```
<button><image src="foo"/></button>
```

You can use a background-image instead of an image tag inside.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you don't bind to the `mouseup` event?

http://jsfiddle.net/kR3P9/

For an image with the id "**example**":

```
function init() {
    var example = document.getElementById("example");
    example.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
       alert("Mouse up!");
    }, false);
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);​
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are attempting to cause the action on the image.  If the image performs an action on a page when you click on it, it is probably wrapped in a  tag already.  Without seeing the page you are working on, I would guess that you can use

```
 $(imageElement).parent("a").click()
```